# React-native-router-flux skipping login/signup when loggedIn state equals true and navigate to a given scene

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am making an app where I have a log in and registrastion part and a mainpart. When the user is logged in, I want him/her to be taken directly to the mainpart for the app. I am using **router-flux**, but couldn't find a way to implement `Actions.mainPart()` when `case: true`. Looking for a way to solve this problem, thank you! Let me know if you need some other code in order to help.

My App.js code:

```
class App extends Component {

   state = { loggedIn: null };

     componentWillMount() {

       const config = {

        };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
  this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
} else {
  this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
}
   });
   }

render() {

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
  case false:
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  case true:
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  default:
    return <Spinner size="large" />;
  }
 }
}

 export default App;
```

Comment: hey, I have the same scenario. any solution to this?